# Output variable not working as expected in bash (azure pipelines)

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am new in Azure Pipelines.

topic 1:

I am trying to set my terraform pipeline in Azure Devops Pipelines to be set as:
when TF Plan job finishes and has the result like "Changes detected", then to run the TF Apply job.
If the TF Plan job contains "No changes" in the -out=terraform.plan , the job should finish and then Tf Apply job should be skipped.

I am trying to use that specific variable `##vso [task.setvariable var=myvar;]abc` but in my context is not working.

Why? I tried a lot of methods to export somehow a variable and to use the variable between jobs (Use outputs in a different stage) but not working.

My case and problem is below:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  name: A
  displayName: "Run tf ${{ parameters.action }}"
  inputs:
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      if [ ${{ parameters.action }} = "plan" ]; then
          echo "Running terraform plan..."
          terraform azure plan -out=terraform.plan
          changes=$(terraform show -no-color terraform.plan | grep -E "No changes.")
          echo "Checking for Changes variable [$changes]"
          if [ -n "$changes" ]; then
            echo "No changes detected. Exiting without further actions."
            echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=anyTfChanges]'$changes
            echo "anyTfChanges $anyTfChanges"
            exit 0
          else
            echo "Changes detected. Setting/exporting anyTfChanges=True"
            echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=anyTfChanges]'$changes
          fi
      else
          echo "Value of anyTfChanges is $anyTfChanges"
          echo "Running terraform apply..."
          terraform apply -input=false -auto-approve
      fi

    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}'
```

The problem is that even if I use bash script (scriptType: 'bash'), the command `echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=anyTfChanges]'$changes` is not interpreted as I wish and it is not setting a variable.

I have tried to see why? I think that because I use task: AzureCLI@2 and when the job starts in pipeline, it says:

```
Pool: Azure Pipelines
Image: ubuntu-20.04
Queued: Just now [manage parallel jobs]
Agent: Azure Pipelines 2
Started: Just now
```

The problem can be Agent used? Have anyone used this ##vso command in this type how I have?

I tried with to export by simple bash command, but not working to reference that variable for the Apply job.
I see in this case `##vso [task.setvariable var=myvar]abc` is the option to achieve my goal (to skip apply job if plan has "no changes" in azure pipelines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a variable in task using `##vso[task.setvariable variable=anyTfChanges]'$changes`, the variable will only become available on subsequent steps in the same yaml job.

Two sidenotes to your question based on your code snippet:

- the syntax you are using to reference the created variable in your code snippet is incorrect. To reference the variable in script, one option you can use is `$(varName)`.
- your logic flow seems a bit strange. `anyIfChanges` is defined in the `if` part of your if/else statement. You are also trying to reference the variable created in the `if` in your `else` segment. This will not work.

See example yaml below on when `varTwo` becomes available:

```
variables:
- name: varOne
  value: value1 

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: "Create and print vars test"
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(serviceConnection)
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |

        echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=varTwo]'value2

        echo $(varOne)    # Output = value1
        echo $(varTwo)    # Output = varTwo: command not found

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: "Print vars test"
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(serviceConnection)
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |

        echo $(varOne)    # Output = value1
        echo $(varTwo)    # Output = value2
```

If you want to make your variable available in different jobs and stages, you can add `;isOutput=true`. [Read on how to do that here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-stage).

Comment: Thank you, Scott! I will try as you recommended. My main issue was that the Agent used Azure Pipelines2 is not interpreting the setting the variable needed ##vso command inside if condition  even if i put itOutput=true; it is processed as a comment in my script even if I use typescript: ‘bash’. I will dig more.

Comment: I tested my snippet using a Microsoft hosted agent, and did not encounter that issue. Maybe as a test, you can do the same to see if that is indeed where the problem is?

Comment: I have added the second part to my initial question... as it was too long to put in a comment.

Where am I wrong when I try to consume that variable?



I am out of solutions right now... I will try new ones later, but a bit strange. I have tried with stageDependencies because the variable output will be shared between these 2 stages.

Comment: @be9inn3r could you please instead close of this question by marking this as the accepted answer, and instead open a new question for your second query. If you add the same set of tags you did on this question, I'll see it and answer it if I can.